# How to smash the stack?

Tags: stack

I have a little assignment of stack smashing.So what is the simplest way to smash the stack?
I just want a simple illustrative method.

Answer (score 6):

Try reading "[Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html)" by Aleph One.

Comment: This should really be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Can't comment on questions (yet?), sorry

Comment: Yea sorry just noticed your rep.